# Dependency Injection in constructor service Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I use TypeScript in Angular.

The service is:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

  public localStorageService: LocalStorageService;

  constructor(private http: Http, private credentials: Credentials, public apiUrl: ApiUrls, localStorageService: LocalStorageService) {
    this.localStorageService = localStorageService;
  }
}
```

Problem is when I try to use this service in component like this:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
  }
}
```

It requires to specify constructor `AuthenticationService` when I try to inject this in component. It is not convenient.

How to improve this code?

I tried to make Fabric:

```
public authenticationFactory: AuthenticationService;

 this.authenticationFactory = (http: Http, credential: Credentials, apiUrl: ApiUrls, localStorage: LocalStorageService) => {
      return new AuthenticationService(http, credential, apiUrl, localStorage);
    };
```

But it calls error on line `this.authenticationFactory`

Comment: What do you mean with "it is not convenient". What is the expected (convenient) behavior? What is the actual behavior? Why do you add it to the constructor when you don't want it to be injected?

Comment: I mean that in component I need to pass all dependencies for service, because it uses  them in constructor

Comment: you add it to the constructor, in order to use the same instance of this service in many component. Angular creates it for you and provide it to the component that request this service in its constructor.

Comment: You mean you want a static service?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly your problem is, but if it's not working, you probably didn't register your service. Add the service to be a part of your module under the `providers`.

Comment: I updated questiom, problem is that my service has dependencies in cinstructor, therefore when I use service I need to pass these dependencies to service constructor

Comment: Your last comment sounds like, I want dependency injection to inject a service, but I don't want to use dependency injection. To me your question still doesn't make sense. If you don't want the service to be injected, then don't add it to the constructor parameter list.

Comment: I need this, but can you offer another way? when service has dependencies

Comment: What is "this" in "need this" and what is wrong with the current way? I still have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: Okay, Let's leave this approach